# "For another same amount of time" in this context

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

The bus arrives at our local bus stop at 8am. The other day my brother and I were going to catch the bus and we went to the bus stop at 7:50am so we had to wait for 10 minutes. My 10-year-old brother was too eager to get on the bus. When it was 7:55 am my brother eagerly asked me:

> How much more do I have to wait?

I answered:

> (You have to wait) for another five minutes.

Could I have answered it a bit differently by saying:

> You have to wait for **the same amount of time that you have already waited.**

Or should I use **for another same amount of time that you have...**?

I'm not a native speaker, Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why make things complex? *Five more minutes...* serves the purpose!

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a common, clear, and concise way to say this in English. Some options are to simply give the time:

> (you have to wait for) another five minutes.

or, somewhat ambiguously:

> (you have to wait) as long as you've waited.

or, precisely but verbosely:

> (you have to wait) as long as you've waited, again.

or giving the time and the fact that it equals the previous wait separately:

> (you have to wait for) another five minutes, which is how long you've waited so far.

The first is, of course, always acceptable, but lacks some of the meaning you were looking for. The third is fine but depending on how advanced the listener's English is, it might be misunderstood. The fourth is most clear and complete, but a little wordy. The second is just a little bit patronizing, and could be misinterpreted to mean the wait is done. I might use it when talking to my siblings, but wouldn't address it to anyone I didn't have a pretty close relationship with already, as it might give offense.

Also note that every use of "another five minutes" could be replaced with "five more minutes" which is a little less formal, and more common in conversational English.

Answer (score 0):

No. *another same* doesn't work.

The idiomatic expression here would be:

> You have to wait the same length of time again.

"Again" here doesn't just mean "one more time": it is a more or less fixed expression *the same time/length/amount/cost again*, meaning "as last time": exactly what you wanted to convey by "another same amount" I think.